# Loop through (possible) multiple arguments

Tags: bash

I wrote a small bash script to check if a website is up or not (using isup.me). It works currently (in terminal I call "sh isup.sh stackoverflow.com"). What I'd like to be able to do is call "sh isup.sh stackoverflow.com someother.site" (two arguments) and loop through the output for each argument.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
theSite=$1
curl isup.me/$theSite | grep 'just' | sed s'/<a href="//' | sed s'/" class="domain">//' | sed s'/<\/a>//' | sed s"/http:\/\/$theSite//" | sed s'/<\/span>//'
```

Another (noncritical) question I have is: can I get rid of the "% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current" bit of the curl function?

Comment: It answered my main question, which is all that I was looking for. However, I see that your response is far superior, so I thank you.

Comment: @kojiro: Both of the other answers address the second part of the question.

Comment: @Johnsyweb so they do. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` accepts multiple URLs, so you just need to build up the list and execute a single command. You can do this pretty simply with a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). As an aside, you don't need to use all those pipes. You can modify the entire thing with a single gsed or awk command. Here's how I would write it:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s "${@/#/http://isup.me/}" |
    awk -F '[<>]' '/just/{
        sub("http://", "", $3);
        print $3 $NF;
    }'
```

Comment: So I've started using this as a geektool script. How do I use the 'awk' command to remove the "It's (not) just you" and the "http://" parts?
(an explanation would be wonderful, but not required)

EDIT:
and it's magically gone now? but not in terminal... what's going on?

Comment: @EricWolf Show me how you're invoking the script "in terminal" and not and maybe I can tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Looping over the `$@` array will give you the arguments starting with the first.

```
for theSite
do
  ...
done
```

Note that by default `for` loops over `$@`.

The `-s` argument will tell cURL to be silent.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this with `for`. This gets my vote.

Comment: Pedantically, `for` loops over `"$@"` by default.

Comment: Even though it's cool to know that "for" loops over $@ by default, I'd rather see it explicitly. (I'm a Python guy and the Zen of Python says "explicit is better than implicit").

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

while (( "$#" )); do
    theSite=$1
    curl isup.me/${theSite} 2>/dev/null | grep 'just' | sed s'/<a href="//' | sed s'/" class="domain">//' | sed s'/<\/a>//' | sed s"/http:\/\/$theSite//" | sed s'/<\/span>//'
    shift
done
```

This iterates while there are still arguments and then [**`shift`**](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)s the arguments leftwards.

`2>/dev/null` redirects [`stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stderr/info) to `/dev/null`, so you don't see that "extra" output.

The `for`-loop in [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888723/78845) is better, since you don't risk "forgetting" the `shift` and creating an infinite loop.You should use that approach.

An alternative approach would be to use [**`w3m`**](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) to render the HTML and make the script much simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash

for theSite; do
    w3m -dump isup.me/${theSite} | grep "${theSite}"
done
```

Comment: The braces aren't required. Did you mean to put quotes instead?

Comment: Not required in this case, no, it's just a habit.